# Is a pre-processor like Babel really necessary for Jest to work for my typescript project?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs

I need to add unit test case for my react application written using typescript. I have chosen Jest for executing unit test case in my application, but i have a doubt is babel required as a pre-processor for Jest or will my Jest work without pre-processor.

Comment: Not an answer, but here is some more information: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html#using-typescript

Comment: Yes, you need a pre-processor so the sources can be compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Jest` runs as a JavaScript application on `Node.js`.

When it runs, it looks for all your test files.

When it finds a test file, it [applies any configured transformers](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/3dd26b4e9e2f3f70ce75522d71b0c12e5baed530/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.ts#L723-L727) before running it [in the way specified by the test environment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/3dd26b4e9e2f3f70ce75522d71b0c12e5baed530/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.ts#L736).

`jsdom` is the default test environment which [runs the script with the `JSDOM` VM](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/3dd26b4e9e2f3f70ce75522d71b0c12e5baed530/packages/jest-environment-jsdom/src/index.ts#L129).

`node` is the other commonly used test environment and it [runs the script in context](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/3dd26b4e9e2f3f70ce75522d71b0c12e5baed530/packages/jest-environment-node/src/index.ts#L105).

**This means that anything that is not plain JavaScript (TypeScript, `JSX`, etc.) needs to be transformed before it can be run in either of these test environments.**

`Babel` is the most common transformer and [`Jest` has some `Babel`-specific configuration that makes it easier to get going](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html#using-babel)...

...but `Babel` is [not the only option](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest#ts-jest-------) and you can specify any transformer you want in the [`Jest` configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-object-string-pathtotransformer-pathtotransformer-object), you can even create your own transformer if you want...

...but yes, any TypeScript needs to be converted to plain JavaScript before it can be run by `Jest` in either the `jsdom` or `node` environments.